# Extract tarball into the same directory

Tags: bash, shell, tar

I have a hierarchy of folders, which contain a lot of tarballs. I need to write a script which recursively goes to each directory, extract the tarball in the corresponding directory.

I tried

```
find ./ -name "*.tar.gz" -exec /bin/tar -zxvf {} \;
```

The code executed with all the tarballs extracted to the pwd, not in the corresponding directory.

Please assist me on this if possible. Thanks :)

Comment: `find`'s `-execdir` option will run the specified command in the matched files' respective directories instead of the `find` process's CWD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use find like this:

```
find . -name "*.tar.gz" -exec bash -c 'd=$(dirname "{}") && b=$(basename "{}") && cd "$d" && tar zxvf "$b"' \;
```

**EDIT** A shorter version of above find command will be:

```
find . -name "*.tar.gz" -execdir tar zxvf "{}" \;
```

Comment: A simpler `find . -name "*.tar.gz" -execdir  tar zxvf "{}" \;` would also have worked.

Comment: This is more like it. I like this answer better. Cleaner. :)